# How can I create a direct link to a specific spreadsheet using the "install site as an app" functionality?

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge I had a shortcut to a Google Sheets document that I made using the "install as an app" functionality. Recently the functionality broke.

I had pop-up notifications on a few of my customized app shortcuts stating that "my_custom_app_name" was going to be renamed to "Sheets".  Following that "renaming" the customization was no longer there.

For example, one custom app link pointed to a Google Sheets document where I store keyboard shortcuts I use across various apps.

I liked the approach of having it listed as a site installed as an app including being able to customize the name and shortcut icon and the way the document was displayed.

Here's a mockup of what opening my spreadsheet as an app looked like.  It was similar to Sheets' native fullscreen view (no menus & buttons) but additionally eliminated browser menus and icons.

[image: A subset of my sheet]

Is there still a supported way to do this or a fairly simple workaround?

Comment: If you want to focus your question on the operative system plus web browser interaction to open a window that looks with certain characteristics like a web browser toolbar hidden, that go beyond crafting a URL, I think that the question should be migrated to Super User, but before doing so, it might be needed to add some details like the name and version of the operative system and a web browser used (you already mentioned be using MS Edge but not the version, nowadays Edge is available for Mac and Linux too, so we can't assume that you are using Windows)

Comment: Once you edit the question, if you want to be migrated instead of just reopened, please flag it for moderator attention, mentioning that you are asking the migration to Super User (or Ask Different if you are using a Mac, or Unix and Linux if you are using Unix and Linux OS, or Ask Ubuntu if you are using Ubuntu).

Comment: If we migrate this question to [su] it may be closed as a  duplicate of [How to add the currently opened website as an Edge app](https://superuser.com/questions/1747043/)  I suspect that while Sheets is not designed to be a PWA it is probably still supplying a manifest which is controlling some of the behavior.  You can find dev resources to sniff out various local settings.  Definitely off-topic for [webApps.se] but interesting.

Comment: @BlindSpots The other question doesn't look to be very clear, and it's not answered. With all that was commented here, including the clarifications that you mentioned to have the intention to add, it might be worth to migrate the question... probably the other one will be closed as duplicate of this one

Comment: I made a quick search and find that it's possible to customize the icon of the installed app, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/278976/chromium-edge-install-this-site-as-an-app-modify-i, it might be possible to customize the landing page to set the spreadsheet instead the Google Sheets app. As I'm not using Windows and Edge regularly, I might be unable to continue accompanying you on this journey. Good Luck!

Comment: Well, who should take the lead about this question content is the OP :)

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks for trying to help. But it does feel like "step away, I'll get you an answer"...  Oh well. Did you took one second to see my bio?  Be gentle please, my computer life's hard here.

Comment: @deryb We value you on Web Apps. While this question is off-topic, I will do some additional investigation and circle back.  Then you/we can decide if the question can be improved and/or migrated.  Interesting problem-space, and you want to have a question that is detailed enough to avoid low-quality answers or no answers.

Comment: @deryb I [started a started a chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148537/discussion-on-question-by-deryb-how-can-i-create-a-direct-link-to-a-specific-spr) for the three of us (and any other interested parties) to discuss this question since it is off-topic on [webapps.se] but is of interest to us.